# scala, filter a collection based on several conditions

Tags: scala

I have a code such as:

```
val strs = List("hello", "andorra", "trab", "world")
def f1(s: String) = !s.startsWith("a")
def f2(s: String) = !s.endsWith("b")

val result = strs.filter(f1).filter(f2)
```

now, f1 and f2 should be applied based on a condition, such as:

```
val tmp1 = if (cond1) strs.filter(f1) else strs
val out  = if (cond2) tmp1.filter(f2) else tmp1
```

is there a nicer way to do this, without using a temporary variable `tmp1`?

one way would to filter based on a list of functions, such as:

```
val fs = List(f1 _,f2 _)
fs.foldLeft(strs)((fn, list) => list.filter(fn))
```

but then I would need to build a list of functions based on the conditions (and so, I would move the problem of using a temporary string list variable, to using a temporary function list variable (or I should need to use a mutable list)).

I am looking something like this (of course this does not compile, otherwise I would already have the answer to the question):

```
val result = 
  strs
    .if(cond1, filter(f1))
    .if(cond2, filter(f2))
```

Comment: Sounds like you want a list of tuples with (condition,filterPredicate). You can then filter this list based on whether or not condition (e.g. _._1) holds. Now you have a list of functions you want to apply. You can then  map this with the string and reduce with && (logic and).  Sorry if it's too wavy.

Comment: thanks, that's a good idea also, but I was looking something more like noah's answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use an implicit class to give you this syntax:

```
  val strs = List("hello", "andorra", "trab", "world")

  def f1(s: String) = !s.startsWith("a")

  def f2(s: String) = !s.endsWith("b")

  val cond1 = true
  val cond2 = true

  implicit class FilterHelper[A](l: List[A]) {
    def ifFilter(cond: Boolean, f: A => Boolean) = {
      if (cond) l.filter(f) else l
    }
  }

  strs
    .ifFilter(cond1, f1)
    .ifFilter(cond2, f2)

res1: List[String] = List(hello, world)
```

I would have used `if` as the method name but it's a reserved word.

Comment: that's what i was looking for; then I can process it in multiple steps as in strs.filter(...).map(...).ifFilter(...).map(...).ifFilter(...). I would only change "l.filter(a => !cond || filter(a))" by "if (cond) l.filter(filter) else l" to avoid using a filter with a always true condition.

Comment: I updated the code to reflect the change, no need to traverse when you don't need to.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by summing your predicate functions.

Observe that a filter predicate, `A => Boolean`, has an append operation:

```
def append[A](p1: A => Boolean, p2: A => Boolean): A => Boolean =
  a => p1(a) && p2(a)
```

And an identity value:

```
def id[A]: A => Boolean =
  _ => true
```

which satisfies the condition that for any predicate `p: A => Boolean`, `append(p, id) === p`.

This simplifies the problem of including/excluding a predicate based on a condition: if the condition is false, simply include the `id` predicate. It has no effect on the filter because it always returns `true`.

To sum the predicates:

```
def sum[A](ps: List[A => Boolean]): A => Boolean =
  ps.foldLeft[A => Boolean](id)(append)
```

Note that we fold onto `id`, so if `ps` is empty, we get the identity predicate, i.e. a filter that does nothing, as you'd expect.

Putting this all together:

```
val predicates = List(cond1 -> f1 _, cond2 -> f2 _)

strs.filter(sum(predicates.collect { case (cond, p) if cond => p }))
// List(hello, world)
```

Note that the list `strs` was only traversed once.

---

Now, for the Scalaz version of the above:

```
val predicates = List(cond1 -> f1 _, cond2 -> f2 _)

strs filter predicates.foldMap {
  case (cond, p) => cond ?? (p andThen (_.conjunction))
}
// List("hello", "world")
```

Comment: the problem is that if cond1=false, you are applying something like "strs.filter(true)", which is slower than just returning the list itself.

Comment: David: but then, if both conditions are true, we still only apply `filter` once. For `n` predicates, your accepted solution will run `filter` up to `n` times!

Comment: Are you saying that these `append` and identity `id` operations/functions exist, or just that they can be defined? I can't find them in Scala 2.10.

Answer (score 3):

@Noah's answer is good, and you can take it and generalize it further if you want to be able to perform any type of action on a list then returns a new List given a condition if you make the following change:

```
implicit class FilterHelper[A](l: List[A]) {
  def ifthen[B](cond: Boolean, f:(List[A]) => List[B]) = {
    if (cond) f(l) else l
  }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
val list = List("1", "2")    
val l2 = list.ifthen(someCondition, _.filter(f1)
val l3 = list.ifthen(someOtherCondition, _.map(_.size))
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be rather simple to just include the condition in your block for the filter, like so:

```
val result = strs filter (x => !cond1 || f1(x)) filter (x => !cond2 || f2(x))
```

whereby the result would apply a filter if the condition is met, or simply return the same list.

Comment: Yes, but I think the point is why even apply the function if if will not do anything.  Why iterate through the list (say it's very big) if you don't have to?

Comment: Could write `strs filter { x => (!cond1 || f1(x)) && (!cond2 || f2(x)) }` so you only traverse once